# Use selenium webdriver with customized web tags made with web components

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

Currently in my test case I need to write tests to be able to find elements of the customized variety made using web components, example of the html code is below:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body class>
    <customtag1 id="app">
      <customtag2 id="app2">
         <div id="divid">
           <customtag3 class="current icon">
              "Text here"
           </customtag3>
         </div>
      </customtag2>
    </customtag1>
```

Now for my selenium test, I have written as follows, written using mocha:

```
  test.it('test', function() {    
    return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag1")).then(function(cus1){
        cus1.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag2")).then(function(cus2){
            cus2.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#divid")).then(function(div){
                    div.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag3 ")).getText();
       })
     })
  })
})
```

However it seems to have trouble finding any element but the first tag, after the first tag returns the promise object, it can not find the web element customtag2, or any remaining elements. Is there another way of doing it? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to resolve the results of `findElement()` command - you can chain the `findElement` commands one by one:

```
var customtag1 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag1"));
var customtag2 = customtag1.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag2"));
var div = customtag2.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#divid"));
var customtag3 = div.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag3"))
customtag3.getText().then(console.log);
```

Or, just reach `customtag3` directly if intermediate elements are not needed:

```
var customtag3 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag1 > customtag2 > #divid > customtag3"));
customtag3.getText().then(console.log);
```

`>` means the direct parent-child relationship. `.then(console.log)` is a short way to do `.then(function (text) { console.log(text); });`.

Comment: Isn't all the element returned from Selenium are promises that needs to be resolved?

Comment: @HarveyLin I was always under the impression that chaining findElement commands works like that in WebDriverJS. Give it a try.

Comment: Does not work, it returns a promise object, and still can not find elements. I can't even print out the innerHTML of the first customtag1

Comment: @HarveyLin wait, does `customtag1.getText().then(console.log);` prints out something on the console?..

Comment: I found the problem but doesn't know the solution yet. The problem is that the webpage I am trying to load have a lot of <link rel="import" herf="xx.html"> tags on the page and it looks like Webdriver is not picking them up, thus returning an empty innerHTML inside the first customized tag.

Comment: @HarveyLin ah, any `iframe`/`frame` elements on a page?

Comment: No, just customized elements generated using web components

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that

```
cus1.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#customtag2")).then(function(cus2){
```

should be

```
cus1.findElement(webdriver.By.css("customtag2")).then(function(cus2){
```

because `customtag` is an element, not an elements id.  The id is `#app2` so that could be used, i.e.

```
cus1.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#app2")).then(function(cus2){
```

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. It will be able to find the top level element, but rest of it doesn't work, like it will throw warning "can not find element customtag2" Also I edited the question to much the suggestion you did.